# Unknown column 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,' setting up CodeIgniter DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Setting up a new CodeIgniter 3 project I'm stucked with a DB access issue. When visiting my home page I get:

```
'Unknown column 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,' in 'field list'
```

...which is fired when Codeigniter initializes the database. After `mysqli/mysqli_driver.php` call `parent::__construct()`

After some code and google resarch is not clear to me why is this happening. Any hints? Suggestions?

*Some details*

Using same database connection I successfully use from others PHP setups in the same dev computer. (with older codeigniter versions)

I use CodeIgniter 3.1.10, installed along with [ci3-fire-starter](https://github.com/JasonBaier/ci3-fire-starter)

My DB config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'          => '',
    'hostname'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username'     => 'my_username', 
    'password'     => 'my_password',
    'database'     => 'my_db',
    'dbdriver'     => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix'     => '',
    'pconnect'     => FALSE,
    'db_debug'     => TRUE,
    'cache_on'     => FALSE,
    'cachedir'     => '',
    'char_set'     => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat'     => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre'     => '',
    'encrypt'      => FALSE,
    'compress'     => FALSE,
    'stricton'     => FALSE, // Notice I have stricton set to FALSE!
    'failover'     => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And finally the full error obtained:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,' in 'field list'

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 203

Backtrace:

File: C:\my\path\application\core\MY_Controller.php
Line: 26
Function: __construct

File: C:\my\path\application\core\Public_Controller.php
Line: 13
Function: __construct

File: C:\my\path\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 10
Function: __construct

File: C:\my\path\index.php
Line: 325
Function: require_once
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/my/path/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

Comment: What does the code around line 325 in index.php, line 10 in Welcome.php, line 13 in Public_Controller.php and line 26 in MY_Controller.php look like? Also, do you have STRICT_ALL_TABLES in any of your MySQL config files, if so, how is it referenced?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Self-answered question, just in case it can be useful to anyone:

It's a pretty weird situation related to codeigniter mysqli driver `class CI_DB_mysqli_driver` at `system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php`. 
For some reason code under:

```
if (isset($this->stricton))         { /* ... */ }
```

...is setting some mysqli MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND options which are causing the error.

It's easy to by-pass the error **not setting**  `'stricton'` flag in you db settings. Just comment it out:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'          => '',
    'hostname'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username'     => 'my_username', 
    'password'     => 'my_password',
    'database'     => 'my_db',
    'dbdriver'     => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix'     => '',
    'pconnect'     => FALSE,
    'db_debug'     => TRUE,
    'cache_on'     => FALSE,
    'cachedir'     => '',
    'char_set'     => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat'     => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre'     => '',
    'encrypt'      => FALSE,
    'compress'     => FALSE,
    // 'stricton'     => FALSE,
    'failover'     => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: I have eneded up commenting out the whole section for 
`if (isset($this->stricton))         { /* ... */ }`
That is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this questions was asked, but I just ran into this issue myself trying to migrate from MySQL 5.2 to 8, so I thought I'd answer it properly for anyone else that may trip over it.

```
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,' in 'field list'
```

The underlying issue here is the sql_mode used. There's a setting ANSI_QUOTES that will make the " an identifier character. Because of that setting, the following code in **mysqli_driver.php** in CodeIgniter fails:

```
if (isset($this->stricton))
        {
            if ($this->stricton)
            {
                $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ",", "STRICT_ALL_TABLES")');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND,
                    'SET SESSION sql_mode =
                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                    @@sql_mode,
                    "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,", ""),
                    ",STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                    "STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                    "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,", ""),
                    ",STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", ""),
                    "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "")'
                );
            }
        }
```

So, two possible solutions:

1. Remove ANSI_QUOTES either at session or global level, or
2. Rework the query by "swapping" single and double quotes:

```
if (isset($this->stricton)) {
            if ($this->stricton) {
                $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, "SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',', 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES')");
            } else {
                $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, "SET SESSION sql_mode =
                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                    @@sql_mode,
                    'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,', ''),
                    ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES', ''),
                    'STRICT_ALL_TABLES', ''),
                    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,', ''),
                    ',STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', ''),
                    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', '')"
                );
            }
        }
```